# Comparing time complexity using ∈ notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

If there are two functions: f(n) and g(n)

If: f(n) ∈ O(g(n))

Is it then true that: 3^(f(n)) ∈ O(3^(g(n)))

Comment: Think about f(n)=2n, g(n)=n.

Comment: Why post this question twice?

Comment: So sorry, I'm sort of new to this and couldn't find my old question, I'll try to remove the other one

Comment: @NateEldredge even if f(n) = 2n , if it has been implied that f(n) is of the set O(g(n)), then it's still true right?

Comment: No, your claim is false, and f(n)=2n, g(n)=n is a counterexample.  The function f(n)=2n is indeed O(g(n)) when g(n)=n.  In other words, 2n ∈ O(n).  Look at the definitions to confirm this.  And then, 2^(2n) is not O(2^n).